# C - Buffersize conditional not breaking while loop

Tags: c, time, while-loop, keypress, break

### UPDATE:
Okay, I'm going about this entirely the wrong way. The reason I'm not geting the result I want is because I'm reading from the terminal and awaiting an enter keypress before the program continues to execute. What I actually need to do is program a "screen" or x11 window to read real-time inputs. Therefore my question is now redundant. Thanks for everyone's suggestions.

Is there a better way to program this which would allow me to capture
`keyPress` time? And, why is the `BUFFERSIZE` conditional in the while loop not
breaking out of the loop?

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 100 

int main(void) {

    int terminalInput;
    int keyPress = 0;
    int inputArrayBuffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    int bufferExceptionFlag = 0;

    printf("\n\t\t\t->");                                   /* Prompt */

    while((terminalInput = getchar()) != '\n' && keyPress < BUFFERSIZE) {
        inputArrayBuffer[keyPress] = terminalInput;
        ++keyPress;

        if (keyPress >= BUFFERSIZE) {
            bufferExceptionFlag = 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `And, why is the BUFFERSIZE conditional in the while loop not breaking out of the loop?` Are you sure? It should, once `keyPress` reaches 100.

Comment: "Is there a better way..." - yes, absolutely. You are basically reading one character at a time, with a maximum of `BUFFERSIZE` characters. There are C library functions for this, namely something like `fgets()`.

Comment: I'd expect the BUFFERSIZE conditional to work but it doesn't and I'm certainly interested to know why. Regards reading one character at a time, this is kind of what i need... like a terminal input sensor as opposed to just a capturing a string from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues. For one, your inputArrayBuffer should be a `char` array, not an `int` array. Secondly, there are standard C libraries that include the functionality of what you want to do.

**Question 1: "Is there a better way to program this which would allow me to capture keyPress time?**"

Yes. For reading `stdin` until either a newline is encountered or a max length is encountered, the `fgets` function from `stdio.h` works nicely (although alternatives may exist). Something like,

```
fgets(inputArrayBuffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin)
```

I understand you want to know the number of keys the user entered, not including the newline key. This is essentially the string length. An easier way to achieve this is to simply determine the length of the string entered by the user. Something like,

```
keyPress = strlen(inputArrayBuffer) - 1; // -1 because the newline '\n' is included in strlen if you use fgets
```

If you must capture a single character at a time, then the original code you proposed should work, just be certain to define inputArrayBuffer as `char inputArrayBuffer[BUFFERSIZE];`

**Question 2: "And, why is the BUFFERSIZE conditional in the while loop not breaking out of the loop?"**

It definitely should be breaking out of the loop. But don't confuse `bufferExceptionFlag` equaling the value 1 with signifying that `keyPress < BUFFERSIZE` didn't cause the loop to break. Clearly, when you `++keyPress` inside the loop, if `keyPress` had the value of 99, it would then become 100, which would cause `bufferExceptionFlag` to be set. However, on the next loop iteration `keyPress < BUFFERSIZE` would be false and the loop would break.

Here is a more simple and appropriate solution in my opinion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFERSIZE 100

int main(void) {
    char inputArrayBuffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    unsigned long keyPress = 0;
    printf("\n\t\t\t->");                                   /* Prompt */
    fgets(inputArrayBuffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin);
    keyPress = strlen(inputArrayBuffer) - 1; // -1 because the newline '\n' is included in strlen if you use fgets
    printf("User entered: %s\n", inputArrayBuffer);
    printf("Input length: %lu\n", keyPress);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that fgets includes the newline character on the string it reads. To remove this character you can do something like `inputArrayBuffer[keyPress] = '\0';`

Comment: Okay, I'm going about this entirely the wrong way. The reason I'm not geting the result I want is because I'm reading from the terminal and awaiting an enter keypress before the program continues to execute. What I actually need to do is program a "screen" or x11 window to read real-time inputs. Therefore my question is now redundant. Thanks for everyone's suggestions.